# XCode Remove Navigation Bar From Tabbed Application

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xcode5

I created an app with XCode (tabbed application) and by default it has 2 ViewController. Then I added few more ViewController on my story board.

but I notice that those first two ViewController are different than ViewController I added.

XCode default ViewController for tabbed application it seems has some kind navigation bar on top. but I don't see it on others.

How to remove this 'navigation bar' on those default ViewController? so it has same appearance like others? thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove this 'navigation bar' go to the document outline in the storyboard. Select the default view and remove the 'Toolbar'.